# Error when trying to load coordinates from .txt file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to load data from a text file into my database, but one of the columns in the database is of type Point(lat,lng).

**Example of row in .txt file:**

```
1    3    exampleString1    POINT(34.123456, 45.678909)   default    NULL    strg2
```

**MySQL Query:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/location/file.txt' INTO TABLE ExampleTable;
```

**MySQL Workbench Error:** 
Error Code: 1416. Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field   0.003 sec

Comment: Well fancy the, its not magic

Comment: It appears this may not be possible at the moment http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**File:**

```bsh
1;3;"example String1";POINT(34.123456, 45.678909);strg2
```

**MySQL Command-Line:**

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ExampleTable`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ExampleTable` (
    ->   `column0` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `column1` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `column2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `column3` GEOMETRY NOT NULL,
    ->   `column4` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/location/file.txt'
    ->   INTO TABLE `ExampleTable`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
    ->   (`column0`, `column1`, `column2`, @`column3`, `column4`)
    ->   SET `column3` := ST_GeomFromText(REPLACE(@`column3`, ',', ''));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `column0`,
    ->   `column1`,
    ->   `column2`,
    ->   ST_AsText(`column3`) `column3`,
    ->   `column4`
    -> FROM
    ->   `ExampleTable`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
column0: 1
column1: 3
column2: example String1
column3: POINT(34.123456 45.678909)
column4: strg2

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a string to a geometry.

create a text field `geom_txt` on your table so you can save `'POINT(34.123456, 45.678909)'`

Then after the load file

```
 UPDATE ExampleTable
 SET geometryField = ST_GeomFromText(geom_txt);
```